# "Could not launch inspector studio.network.inspection" when using App Inspector on Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1.1 with WiFi pairing

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, wireless-debugging

When we use a "pair device using WiFi" in Android Studio Bumblebee version 2021.1.1, in the "App Inspection" section, it gives us an error in reading the "Database".

> Could not launch inspector studio.network.inspection: Inspector with given id studio.network.inspection already exists. It was launched by project: sap.
>
> This could happen if you launched the same inspector from two different projects at the same time, or if a previous run of the current project crashed unexpectedly and didn't shut down properly.
>
> [Restart]

<sup>[Original screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M29NJ.jpg)</sup>

Nothing happened after pressing the "Restart" button.

How to fix it?

Comment: There is a similar question on Stack Overflow, but it hasn't been answered yet: [How to successfully Restart App Inspection in Android Studio Bumblebee](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70098610/2821954).

Answer (score 1):

Kill app and restart work for me again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).